# Can I get an ORDER BY with several columns but still deterministic?

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, deterministic, non-deterministic

I know that a *deterministic* `ORDER BY` is when you sort by a `UNIQUE INDEX` column, 1) is this true?.

I want to sort by the columns `name` and `percentage`.

There is a possibility that 2 or more students have the **same `name` and the same `percentage`**, therefore, the `ORDER BY` in that case would be *non-deterministic* because `MySQL` would define which one to put first and which one to put after (**not me**), 2) is this true?

So, my third question is (the main one), if I want to sort by several columns but still have a *deterministic* order, should I use a `UNIQUE INDEX` column *at the end of all my columns*, e.g.

`ORDER BY name, percentage, id`?

Considering that the `id` is the `primary key`

I still don't know if I understand *deterministic* and *non-deterministic* correctly.

Comment: Yes, if you add a unique column as the last column in `ORDER BY` you will get a consistent, deterministic ordering.

Comment: You not only should add that id column to the order by clause, you should add it to the select list as well, otherwise you can't even tell two students with the same name apart :)

Comment: hi @Barmar, so, the answer to my 3 questions is "yes", i.e. is it ok as I understand it?

Comment: Almost forgot :) @Shadow. I can put *any* number of columns, right?, the important thing is that they come with a `UNIQUE INDEX` at the end in the ORDER BY, right?

Comment: Expanding slightly on Barmar's comment: You can order by something without selecting it.

Comment: @gus it depends - see Barmar's answer below

Comment: hi @Bohemian, does this mean that we can literally sort by *any* column of the base tables involved (the `FROM`/`JOIN`s columns)?

Comment: @gus More than that, you can sort by any *expression*

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the complementary information, I will do some tests about it. @Bohemian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Not necessarily. If the results don't contain any duplicates in the `ORDER BY` columns, the order will be deterministic.
2. Yes, if there are duplicates the the results are non-deterministic.
3. Yes, adding a unique column to the `ORDER BY` makes it deterministic.

Whether this matters depends on your application.
It can be important if you're doing query-based replication and you use `INSERT INTO table SELECT ...`. Without deterministic ordering, you may get inconsistent `AUTO_INCREMENT` IDs between the master and replicas.

Comment: "*Whether this matters depends on your application.*" - Ok, I need an HTML view to display the rows of a query (**a paginator**), so I think it is necessary that the order is *deterministic* to have consistent pages, right? @Barmar

Comment: Yes. Although you can still get inconsistencies if the table is changed while paging. That's what happens if when you page in the Stack Exchange "hot questions" page.

Comment: Of course, you are right, but this is "by nature" of the changing information, right? (unless we lock the tables, but that would be another topic) @Barmar

Comment: Yes, that's inherent in viewing changing data. But some applications do pagination differently -- they make a snapshot, and you page through that. In this case, you don't have to worry about consistency across queries.

Comment: Great, now it's clear to me. I didn't know about the "snapshot", I will investigate more about it, so far marked as best answer @Barmar

Comment: Hi @Barmar, if I have multiple `JOIN`s (and therefore there will be *many columns* from multiple tables), can I use a `UNIQUE INDEX` from any table that is in the `FROM/JOIN` clause?

Comment: ..or, does it have to be a `UNIQUE INDEX` of a **certain table** of the `FROM/JOIN` clause? @Barmar

Comment: Indexes are not really relevant. What matters is whether there are any duplicates in the result set. The only relevance of indexes is that when a column is unique, you know that it won't have any duplicates. But when you start joining tables, you can create duplicates of unique columns if they join with multiple rows.

Comment: "*But when you start joining tables, you can create duplicates of unique columns if they join with multiple rows*" - Exactly @Barmar, you have understood well the objective of my question. So, as a conclusion, could it be any `UNIQUE INDEX` of any `FROM/JOIN` table, or what would be your answer as a conclusion. For example, for a paginator

Comment: ... i.e., to create a deterministic ORDER BY @Barmar

Comment: The ORDER BY should contain all the columns that guarantee a unique ordering in the result. The specifics depend on the actual query (`GROUP BY` changes things, for instance). It's hard to give a generic answer when joins are involved.

Comment: Ok, for example, a *primary key* (e.g. `users.id`) can appear several times in the result set if it has several associated records in another table, so MySQL would not know which one to put first if it will use ONLY `ORDER BY users.id`, is that what you mean? @Barmar

Comment: Exactly. So you might do `ORDER BY table1.id, table2.date`. `table2.date` doesn't necessarily have to be a unique key, but if there's are no duplicates for each ID it's enough for a consistent ordering.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1. Yes
2. Yes, but to be more concrete: It's the quick sort algorithm which mysql uses to sort the data that causes the randomness.
3. If you need a deterministic query then yes, this is a good way.